# Typescript add import with compiler API

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to use the typescript compiler API to add to transpiled code some imports. The idea is:

This is before:

```
// index.ts
export * from './user.repository'
```

After transpiled:

```
//index.ts
import './save.user.repository.extension'
import './delete.user.repository.extension'
export * from './user.repository'
```

I try to use ts.createPrinter but the result file not contains the imports. How I can append the imports to the file in compile time?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have the logic to find the files and I use the visitor to find the export.